# Delete the 'Cleaning all the gems on your system is dangerous!' message on bundler install

Tags: rubygems, bundler

I would like to know if it's possible to remove the following message on `bundler install` commands:

> Cleaning all the gems on your system is dangerous! If you're sure you
>   want to remove every system gem not in this bundle, run `bundle clean --force`.

From what I understood, this message is supposed to be displayed `bundler clean`, so I don't understand why it would be here. Could it be that it is due to that time I used `bundler install --clean`?

Thank you in advance. Have a nice day.

P.S.: Please warn me if the question should be on another OverFlow website, or with other tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for me was to delete the `.bundle/config` which contained `BUNDLE_CLEAN: "true"`.
The reference of the original comment in GitHub can be found [here](https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/issues/6250#issuecomment-388714079)

Comment: Thanks for the reference link. Good to see the warning are simply due to a bug and is safe to disable.

Answer (score 12):

The warning is due to *bundler* trying to run `bundle clean` after each `install` or `update`.

`bundler config clean false` and `bundler config --local clean false` should be able to disable those attempts, leading to the suppression of the warning.

P.S.: I do not know if that could create problems, as it is not simply suppressing an useless warning, so I won't mark this answer as the selected answer for now, to avoid misleading people with the same problem.

Comment: This helped me since I was executing bundle install in an docker environment where it caused an exit code 15 and thus my build command to fail. Without cleansing it runs perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could be of help!  I hope it won't create bugs elsewhere, however.